# (SOLVED) - Error when sending money (C++ QT SDK)

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk

I had this working before (like a week ago) but now I am having issues with sending money to an account. I keep getting this error string 
"Error transferring https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/transactions - server replied: Bad Request"
but nothing in my code is different. Bellow is my Send Money function.

```
 Network::useTestNetwork();
 Server* server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");

 AccountResponse* sourceAccount = server->accounts().account(source);
 QObject::connect(sourceAccount, &AccountResponse::ready, [sourceAccount, 
 source, dest, server]()
 {
  qint64 sequenceNumber = sourceAccount->getSequenceNumber();
  Account* account = new Account(source, sequenceNumber);

  // Start building the transaction.
  Transaction::Builder *builder = new Transaction::Builder(account);
  builder->addOperation(new PaymentOperation(dest, new AssetTypeNative(), "10"));
  builder->addMemo(Memo::text("Test"));
  Transaction * mTrans = builder->build();

  // Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
  mTrans->sign(source);
  server->submitTransaction(mTrans);

 });
```

EDIT:
I was making a mistake creating accounts which meant creating the same account over and over. The bad request refer to the fact I was trying to transfer credit from one account to the same account. Anyway all fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was working before, a couple of things to check are:
- Does the source wallet have enough XLM remaining to complete the transaction?
- It is possible congestion on the testnet caused a timeout (I ran into this recently). See https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/errors/timeout.html